# Fake thermostat with resistor

Tags: resistors, thermistor

I have a thermostat (think pt100)

[image: sensor on thermostat]

This should be connected to a heating solution. I want to fake the temperature from thermostat, so I was thinking to buy a resistor with the ohms at the temperature I want to fake.

Would it be right to just replace this resistor with the new one with a fixed ohm?

The reason for this is so i can controll when the heating system should start/stop based on more options than only the temperature of one room (my plan is to ha a nc-no relay to switch between two resistors, one with "warm enought" resistance and an other with "not warm enought" resistance

Comment: Why not just bypass the thermostat if you don’t want it to control?

Comment: I want to be able to tell the heating solution when to start and when to stop. So thats why i was thinking two resistors. One for too cold and one for too warm. If i disconnect the termostat, the heat er will allways be on

Answer (score 4):

1. First of all, PT100 is not *thermostat*, its a type of [resistance thermometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resistance_thermometer). And that by the way looks like an PTC thermistor.
2. Technically yes you can do so, It's very wrong and dangerous but you can do that. You are asking why it's dangerous? well, your heating device is using the resistance thermometer to get feedback from real temperature. When you are replacing the temperature sensor with a fixed resistor, you are breaking the feedback loop. the device is designed to read the from that certain type of sensor, let's assume the resistance of the sensor is 100K for say 20 °C, and you are replacing the sensor with a fixed 100K resistor, and set the goal temperature to 20 °C, the device is probably going to deceived into turning the heating system off, but problem starts when your resistor's value for any reason starts change (because they are not ideal), heating system will try to increase or decrease the temperature to meet the desired temperature, which will never be reached, and that will result in system damage.
3. if you want to replace a resistance sensor with a resistor make sure that the resistor is completely fixed, otherwise you are going to end up with a highly unstable open-loop system with a large gain on the input.

Comment: The Pt100 is so-called because it is 100 Ω at 0°C. It will be (from memory) about 136 Ω at 100°C. (I think this makes it a PTC rather than NTC.) The device in the photo doesn't look like a Pt100 anyway. Tip: SE supports HMTL entities `&Omega;`, `&deg;`, `&mu;`, etc. in the posts but not in the comments.

Comment: Thank you for a very detailed answer. The reason  i actually want to do this is so i can use many thermostats to start or stop the heater. Today there is a termostat in each room, but the heating system only support one that should be "centrally located" in the house. In this way it is difficult to adjust the temperature in each room. (the other part, read termostats, opening/closing valves etc is already taken care of)  the heating solution has an internal termostat and will stop heating once the water reach a certain temp.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you could do that, assuming it’s actually a resistive sensor. The part looks like a PTC silicon resistance sensor to me, similar to an RTD. If it’s a diode or other non-resistive sensor it may not work.

The thermostat would then act like a switch if you crank it one side or the other of the fixed temperature the resistor is pretending to represent.

Make sure the thermostat is **always** properly connected (probably in series for heating) with at least one working thermostat or the heat will remain on continuously or off continuously, which could be unhealthy or dangerous (frozen pipes, which burst when thawed for example, or heat stroke). An external switch might make things more clear to the user.